# mean_validation_score vs. numpy.mean(cv_validation_scores)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm using GridSearchCV from scikit-learn in order to compare several models with different hyperparameter settings.

According to the [API documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html), given a specific grid of parameters I can access to its corresponding named tuple **grid_scores_**, which in turn has the following three attributes:

- *parameters*: a dict of parameter settings
- *mean_validation_score*: the mean score over the cross-validation folds
- *cv_validation_scores*: the list of scores for each fold

I have noticed however that the value of *mean_validation_score* does not exactly match with the value that I would get if I explicitly computed the mean of all the cross-validation scores, doing something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

explicit_mean_validation_score = np.mean(cv_validation_scores)
```

The difference between the two mean values is not massive; in fact it is in the order of 0.0001 and therefore it shouldn't eventually impact on the ultimate result. Still, I'm curious to see if anyone of you guys knows exactly why this is happening.

As a brave guess, I would say that this has to deal with some differences between the float precision used internally by scikit-learn when it values *mean_validation_score* and the one used when I explicitly compute the mean of all the *cv_validation_scores* via numpy.

In this regard, I have also checked out what happens at the source code level by looking into the grid_search.py [Git repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/grid_search.py) but I didn't come to an answer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can it be that the number of points in each fold is slightly different (by 1) and scikit-learn accounts for this?

Comment: So, basically you're guessing that scikit-learn may compute a sort of weighted average (instead of just an average) across the folds by taking into account the number of instances of each validation set on each fold (which of course might be slightly different one from each other...). That could actually make sense! Thanks :)